# Can you create a Range variable of all 2136 kanji letters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range, cjk, kanji

I currently creating a simple Japanese learning application in Ruby on Rails.

I have a Word model that needs to create a Kanji model if it contains a kanji character.

At first, I though of using Regex but after some digging, I found that in my case, I can create Range object that can capture a wide range of kanji characters

For example, `"一".."時"` will have a total count of 6211 letters (some of these are not even kanji letters, they're radicals).

My question is, is how do I roughly capture all standard 2136 kanji letters that Japanese learn, in a range object?

Comment: A `Range` has a start and an end. That means if the required letters are not defined in one range but in multiple ranges interrupted by unwanted characters then you cannot use a `Range`. Instead, you need to create an `Array` or `Set` on your own, for example, by concatenating all sub-ranges that only include the desired letters. Or you might want to consider using a gem like [`common_kanjis`](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/common_kanjis).

Comment: _"some of these are not even kanji letters, they're radicals"_ – so a word containing these radicals would be treated by your Kanji model – is that an actual problem?

Comment: A Japanese word and, if I'm not wrong, any Chinese word do not contain radicals.
They serve as building blocks for the kanji letters.

They're not actual letters, in short.